# C#でLivedoorAPI AtomPubで画像アップロード

Tags: c#

PHPではできているんですが、C#だとどうしてもできません。画像をアップロードし、返ってきたHTMLコードを取得したいです。
コンパイル通ります。

```
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        var xdeclaration = xdoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);
        xdoc.AppendChild(xdeclaration);
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create
                ("http://rootend");

        // ローカル,今だけ画像URL
        string img = "http://c.jpg";
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.Headers.Add("X-WSSE", wsseHeader());
        req.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        req.GetResponse();

        Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream();

        //Console.WriteLine(xdoc.ToStringXml());
        Console.WriteLine("habe = " + req.HaveResponse);
        Console.WriteLine(req);
```

PHPではこうなります。

```
require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';
$pwd = 'API_KEY';
$id = 'LIVE_ID';
$url1= 'https://livedoor.blogcms.jp/atompub/hogehoge';
$imgfiles = array(
                 "http://a.jpg",
                 "http://b.jpg");

foreach($imgfiles as $imgfile) {
    $imgdata = file_get_contents($imgfile);
    $content_type = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($imgfile));

    try{
         $req = new HTTP_Request2();
         $req->setUrl($url1);
         $req->setConfig(array('ssl_verify_host' => false,
                               'ssl_verify_peer' => false
                               ));
         $req->setHeader("Content-Type", $content_type);
         $req->setHeader('Expect', '');
         $req->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST);
         $req->setAuth($id, $pwd);
         $req->setBody($imgdata);

         $response = $req->send();
         $xml = simplexml_load_string($response->getBody());
        $src = $xml->content['src'];
        var_dump($response);
```

参考にしたサイト
http://nekoriki.net/57

LivedoorAPI公式
http://help.blogpark.jp/archives/52372407.html

Comment: `img` が変数を宣言するだけでどこにも使われていませんよ

Comment: PHPでいうreq.setBody()をC#で教えてください。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GetRequestStream()` で書き込み用ストリームを取得して `CopyTo` で書きこんで下さい。

```
using(Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ())
{
    using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(img, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        fs.CopyTo(dataStream);
    }
}
```

コードは試してないのでお気を付けて。もっと簡単にやるのならば、`WebClient` を使った方がいいと思います。`UploadData` という関数1コールで実現出来ます。

Comment: この場合`Read`や`Write`を使わなくても`fileStream.CopyTo(dataStream)`で良いかと

Comment: 書き換えました。出先でビルド試せないので助かりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 「リモート サーバーがエラーを返しました: (401) 許可されていません」となってしまいます。

Comment: 画像はアクセス許可、Everyoneになっています。

Comment: それはサーバが Basic 認証やOAuth/WSSE等の認証機能を持っており、何も認証を行っていない、もしくはユーザやパスワード、トークンが間違っている場合に返されます。上記の例だと何も認証処理がありませんので当然の結果となります。おそらく Atompub だと WSSE 認証だと思いますのでそちらを勉強し、その上で別の質問をするのが良いと思います。

Comment: WSSE認証はこちらを参考にして作りました。[リンク](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/tekk/touch/20110220/1298209997)

Comment: wsseHeader() が間違っているのだと思います。WSSE の認証実装は、サーバによって結構ブレがあるのでどのサーバを使っているかを書くと回答が貰いやすいかもしれません。出来れば別の質問にされた方がいいと思います。

Comment: WSSEヘッダーを見直します。このたびは大変助かりました。